# Is there a way to restrict apps based on IP?

Tags: django

I'd like to be able to only allow certain apps to be used from the corporate office which has a static IP. Is there a django package that I can use to do this? If so do you know if it can be used as an additional security measure? Certain apps and the data in those apps I wouldnt want to be accessible by anyone outside the office. I already have pretty good app security but as an additional security measure is this a good option? Thanks

Comment: I dont think u need more packages.Use allowed host array to define the white listed host ip's

Comment: Thank you. I'd like certain apps with less sensitive data to be accessible on various IP addresses since we have a couple offices and some employees need to access the site when working from home. I just want to allow only 1 IP address for other apps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what I'm looking for... 
django-iprestrict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html 
That package will let you either allow or deny by default and set IP whitelists or blacklists per app –

Comment: This project is not being maintained and does not work for the later versions of django. There's another project called [django-iprestrict-redux](https://github.com/sztamas/django-iprestrict-redux) to make this a little more updated.

Answer (score 6):

Just include this middleware class under the `'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES'` variable in your `settings.py` file.

Also include the variable `BLOCKED_IPS = ('123.123.123.123',)` variable, where the value is a tuple of IP addresses you want blocked from your site.

```
  """
   simple middlware to block IP addresses via settings 
   variable BLOCKED_IPS
  """
  from django.conf import settings
  from django import http

  class BlockedIpMiddleware(object):
      def process_request(self, request):
          if request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] in settings.BLOCKED_IPS:
             return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')
          return None
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to only allow an IP address or ip address touple rather than block?

Comment: Yes. You can put your allowed ip. In your settings.py file ALLOWED_HOST = [192.168.56.78]. If its helpful vote this answer.

Comment: I only want to do this for certain apps in my site though, not the whole site

Comment: you can restrict a view for certain user using django decorators[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/decorators/]

Answer (score 1):

There is a library I have been having my eye on, [Django IP Restrict](https://django-iprestrict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I suggest you give a try and tell us your experiance too with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is partly based on answer by Ramesh K, with changes for Django 2.2.19. On the server that I use: the load-balancer puts the IP address received into the "X-Real-IP" header (and also passes the "X-Forwarded-For" header as a comma-separated list of IP addresses). Then the "REMOTE_ADDR" contains load-balancer address, rather than the actual remote address.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import http

class BlockedIpMiddleware:
   def __init__(self, get_response):
      # One-time configuration and initialization, when the webserver starts.
      self.get_response = get_response


   def __call__(self, request):
      # Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later
      # middleware) are called.

      # if request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] in settings.BLOCKED_IPS:
      
      if request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] in settings.BLOCKED_IPS:
         return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')

      return self.get_response(request)
```